# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when doing large API request

Tags: python, json, api

I am using a script to fill a python list with data I get from an API request.
However, I am getting the following error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The rate limit of the API is 500 per request and 200 request per minute which I am not exceeding since the package I am using does this in a loop.

This happens every time when reaching 49000 results.
Any idea why this happens?

Thanks!

Output of error:

```html
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-c4c6bcbc9cbd> in <module>()
     10 cache = []
     11 
---> 12 for c in gen:
     13     cache.append(c)
     14 

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psaw/PushshiftAPI.py in _query(self, kind, stop_condition, **kwargs)
    100                     limit = 0
    101 
--> 102             results = self._get(kind, payload)
    103             if self._limited(payload):
    104                 yield results

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psaw/PushshiftAPI.py in _get(self, kind, payload)
     81             success = response.status_code == 200
     82             i+=1
---> 83         response_json = json.load(response.text)
     84         outv = response_json['data']
     85         if self._limited(payload):

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is my input code:
I am using this .py package:
https://github.com/dmarx/psaw/blob/master/psaw/PushshiftAPI.py

```html
gen = api.search_comments(subreddit = 'Ripple', before= 1514764799, after = 1483228801, sort= 'desc', filter = ['body', 'id','author', 'subreddit','score'])
                                                                        
max_response_cache = 10000
cache = []

for c in gen:
    cache.append(c)

    # Omit this test to actually return all results. Wouldn't recommend it though: could take a while, but you do you.
    #if len(cache) >= max_response_cache:
       # break

# If you really want to: pick up where we left off to get the rest of the results.
if False:
    for c in gen:
        cache.append(c)
```

Comment: The error is a bit cryptic but it means that there wasn't a character at line 1 col 1 - meaning you passed in an empty string. You could check that condition before the decode and do whatever you think appropriate.

Comment: ...ammending that! You can get this error with any non-json payload. Perhaps the best thing is to catch the error, and print the bad payload (or the first bit of it anyway).

Comment: @NickA  have updated my code and question

Comment: @tdelaney i have updated my code and question

Comment: As tdelaney said, you'll need to figure out what the API is returning at that point, because it apparently isn't JSON.